# cwrsync permissions on private key

Tags: windows-8, ssh, cwrsync

I installed [cwRsync](https://www.itefix.net/content/cwrsync-free-edition) 5.3.0 on Windows 8, and I want to set up password-less SSH. I ran ssh-keygen to create the keys, and copied the public key to the remote box. But when I try to SSH, I get this:

```
C:\>ssh myuser@myhost
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0660 for '/cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: /cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
```

How can I change the file's permissions, so cwRsync won't see it as being group-readable? I tried removing the Windows permission inheritance from it, and removing access by anyone but my user. But that seems to have no effect.

Comment: did you try the usual solution: running `chmod 600 /cygdrive/c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa` in a cygwin shell ?

Comment: I only installed cwRsync, not the full cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into the same scenario where I installed cwrsync and didn't have access to chmod via cygwin or other. I was able to fix this using rysnc.exe itself:

Add rsync.exe to your %PATH% if it isn't already there:

```
PATH=%PATH%;c:\path\to\cwrsync\bin
```

Change to the folder that your SSH private key is located:

```
cd c:\users\myuser\.ssh\
```

Use rsync to perform a local copy of your SSH private key using the chmod switch (700=u+rwx,g=,o=):

```
rsync --chmod=700 id_dsa id_dsa.bak
```

Ensure that the rsync command ran successfully by typing each file to ensure the content is the same:

```
type id_dsa
type id_dsa.bak
```

Overwrite the original SSH private key with the .bak (which now has the correct permissions):

```
move id_dsa.bak id_dsa
```

Test SSH to make sure it is working now:

```
ssh -i id_dsa myuser@myhost
```

Comment: Very nice hack to use rsync itself to set permissions. Alas it didn't work for me (Win7, 64bit). I fixed it by selecting the `.ssh` folder, disabling inherited permissions from parent and setting "Full Control" to my own account. Then `cwrsync` worked!

Answer (score 2):

I've recently run into this issue and phiz's answer didn't work for me. However, Stéphane's solution in comments was helpful and I felt it should be a proper answer rather than a comment.

**TLDR: Set Windows permissions on the .ssh folder to full access for yourself and nobody else.**

Locate the directory where cwRsync keeps your ssh keys (possibly `c:\home\username\.ssh` or `<path to cwRsync install>\home\username\.ssh`). Use the Windows permissions dialog to remove all inherited permissions from this directory, and set full control to your own account only.

(Note that I found it necessary to remove permissions from SYSTEM and Administrators for this to work. It may still work with one or other present, but I removed both at once and found it to work that way.)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I still get:  `Permissions 0770 for '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open`.